# Component Dragging Problem - Altium - PCB editor

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm not new to Altium Designer; I have been actively using it for at least one year and I have a very weird problem.

I completed a huge PCB project about 2 months ago. Recently, I realized there was a small mistake in the schematic and I wanted to fixed it. I just swapped the two connections of a component (ie. swapped the TX/RX connection). After I had made the change in schematic and hadsaved it, I moved to the PCB editor (Layout) to do the small trace swapping operation.

But interestingly, the components that were affected from the fixing in in the schematic started to act weird: I can't move those four components where I want, but the others are all good. When I drag and release a component, it returns to the far corner/border of the PCB editor by itself.

I have tried all the ["placement modes"](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/((Smart+Component+Placement))_AD) for component placement, but that didn't solve the problem. Interestingly, there is no such problem in my other projects. You can see everything clearly [in my video that I have uploaded.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS2WoANAfxg)

If anyone has encountered this problem, please help me!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the components and running "update pcb" to create them again?

Answer (score 1):

I think that trying place your component from schematic with "cross probe mode" on can help with this.
I do it this way:

1. split schematic and pcb to 2 windows
2. when you are on schematic window press ctrl+shift+x to turn on cross probe mode and the press ctrl+shift+y to turn on automatic drag
3. now you can click component on schematic and then component on pcb should be selected and picked up under your mouse, ready to place anywhere

Comment: Wow! Even though the solution you offered doesn't solve the actual problem, it is a very nice work-around solution that solves the problem of replacing that four component in my case. It worked! Thank you!

Comment: Also note that I have reverted back the PCB_v2.16 to an older version PCB_v2.15, the problem has gone itself. There is no change, nothing different...But it is fixed now somehow.